# Continuous and RealTime planning update issue

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am not seeing the shift assignments update correctly in the advance although All other elements (patterns) are updating including requests.I am running a 14 day shift roster for 12 employees. 11 must work 9 days per fortnight 1 must work 5 days per fortnight. (104 shift). Can anyone see anything glaringly wrong with my code and or approach. FYI I have tried all differing weighting methods.

I have implemented a load balanced solution based on the tennis example. This works great for the case of all employees working fulltime 9 shifts  (108 shifts). All elements update correctly. Request, unwanted patterns etc and advances well. Maintaining all patterns, requests and shift requirements

```
private void advancePlanningWindowStart() {
        logger.info("Advancing planningWindowStart.");
        if (solutionBusiness.isSolving()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.getTopLevelAncestor(),
                    "The GUI does not support this action yet during solving.\nOptaPlanner itself does support it.\n"
                            + "\nTerminate solving first and try again.",
                    "Unsupported in GUI", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        doProblemFactChange(scoreDirector -> {
            NurseRoster nurseRoster = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
            NurseRosterParametrization nurseRosterParametrization = nurseRoster
                    .getNurseRosterParametrization();

            List<ShiftDate> shiftDateList = nurseRoster.getShiftDateList();

            Shift oldLastShift = nurseRoster.getShiftList()
                    .get(nurseRoster.getShiftList().size() - 1);
            long shiftId = oldLastShift.getId() + 1L;
            int shiftIndex = oldLastShift.getIndex() + 1;
            ShiftDate oldLastShiftDate = shiftDateList
                    .get(shiftDateList.size() - 1);
            long shiftDateId = (oldLastShiftDate.getId() + 1L);
            int shiftDayIndex = (oldLastShiftDate.getDayIndex() + 1);

            scoreDirector
                    .beforeProblemPropertyChanged(nurseRosterParametrization);

            // Update to get the first day along with adding 14 days to the run
            LocalDate startDate = (oldLastShiftDate.getDate().plusDays(1));
            LocalDate endDate = (oldLastShiftDate.getDate().plusDays(14));
            int maxDayIndex = Math.toIntExact(DAYS.between(startDate, endDate));
            int shiftDateSize = maxDayIndex + 1;
            List<ShiftDate> newshiftdateList = new ArrayList<>(shiftDateSize);
            shiftDateMap = new HashMap<>(shiftDateSize);
            LocalDate date = startDate;
            for (int i = 0; i < shiftDateSize; i++) {
                ShiftDate shiftDate = new ShiftDate();
                shiftDate.setId(shiftDateId);
                shiftDate.setDayIndex(shiftDayIndex);
                shiftDate.setDate(date);
                shiftDate.setShiftList(new ArrayList<>());
                shiftDateMap.put(date, shiftDate);
                shiftDateId++;
                shiftDayIndex++;
                date = date.plusDays(1);
                nurseRoster.getShiftDateList().add(shiftDate);
                newshiftdateList.add(shiftDate);
                scoreDirector.afterProblemFactAdded(shiftDate);

            }

            List<Skill> skillList;

            List<Skill> skillElementList = (List<Skill>) nurseRoster
                    .getSkillList();
            skillList = new ArrayList<>(skillElementList.size());
            skillMap = new HashMap<>(skillElementList.size());

            for (Skill element : skillElementList) {
                Skill skill = new Skill();
                long skillid = element.getId();
                skill.setId(skillid);
                skill.setCode(element.getCode());
                Skill skillnew = scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(skill);
                skillList.add(skillnew);
                if (skillMap.containsKey(skillnew.getCode())) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "There are 2 skills with the same code ("
                                    + skill.getCode() + ").");
                }
                skillMap.put(skillnew.getCode(), skillnew);

            }

            List<Contract> contractElementList = (List<Contract>) nurseRoster
                    .getContractList();

            List<Contract> contractList = new ArrayList<>(
                    contractElementList.size());

            contractMap = new HashMap<>(contractElementList.size());

            for (Contract element : contractElementList) {
                Contract contract = new Contract();
                long Id = element.getId();
                contract.setId(Id);
                contract.setCode(element.getCode());
                contract.setDescription(element.getDescription());
                WeekendDefinition weekend = element.getWeekendDefinition();
                contract.setWeekendDefinition(weekend);
                contract.setContractLineList(new ArrayList<ContractLine>());
                Contract contractnew = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(contract);
                contractMap.put(contractnew.getCode(), contractnew);
                contractList.add(contractnew);

            }

            List<Employee> employeeElementList = (List<Employee>) nurseRoster
                    .getEmployeeList();
            Employee oldLastEmployee = nurseRoster.getEmployeeList()
                    .get(nurseRoster.getEmployeeList().size() - 1);
            long empId = oldLastEmployee.getId() + 1L;
            List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>(
                    employeeElementList.size());

            employeeMap = new HashMap<>(employeeElementList.size());

            for (Employee element : employeeElementList) {

                Employee employee = new Employee();
                String name = element.getName();
                String code = element.getCode();

                employee.setId(empId);
                empId++;
                Contract c = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(element.getContract());
                employee.setCode(code);
                employee.setContract(c);
                employee.setName(name);

                employeeList.add(employee);

                employeeMap.put(employee.getName(), employee);
                scoreDirector.afterProblemFactAdded(employee);

            }

            List<ShiftTypeSkillRequirement> coverRequirementElementList = (List<ShiftTypeSkillRequirement>) nurseRoster
                    .getShiftTypeSkillRequirementList();
            List<ShiftType> shiftTypeElementList = (List<ShiftType>) nurseRoster
                    .getShiftTypeList();
            List<ShiftType> shiftTypeList = new ArrayList<>(
                    shiftTypeElementList.size());
            shiftTypeMap = new HashMap<>(shiftTypeElementList.size());
            int index = 0;
            long shiftTypeSkillRequirementId = 0L;
            List<ShiftTypeSkillRequirement> shiftTypeSkillRequirementList = new ArrayList<>(
                    shiftTypeElementList.size() * 2);

            for (ShiftType shiftelement : shiftTypeElementList) {

                ShiftType shiftType = new ShiftType();
                long Id = shiftelement.getId();
                shiftType.setId(Id);
                shiftType.setCode(shiftelement.getCode());
                shiftType.setIndex(index);
                String startTimeString = shiftelement.getStartTimeString();
                shiftType.setStartTimeString(startTimeString);
                String endTimeString = shiftelement.getEndTimeString();
                shiftType.setEndTimeString(endTimeString);
                shiftType
                        .setNight(startTimeString.compareTo(endTimeString) > 0);
                shiftType.setDescription(shiftelement.getDescription());
                ShiftType shiftTypenew = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(shiftType);
                for (ShiftTypeSkillRequirement skillElement : coverRequirementElementList) {
                    ShiftTypeSkillRequirement shiftTypeSkillRequirement = new ShiftTypeSkillRequirement();
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirement
                            .setId(shiftTypeSkillRequirementId);
                    ShiftType shiftTypen = scoreDirector
                            .lookUpWorkingObject(shiftType);
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirement.setShiftType(shiftTypen);

                    Skill skill = skillMap
                            .get(skillElement.getSkill().getCode());
                    Skill skillnew = scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(skill);
                    if (skillnew == null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The skill ("
                                + skillElement.getSkill().getCode()
                                + ") of shiftType (" + shiftType.getCode()
                                + ") does not exist.");
                    }
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirement.setSkill(skillnew);
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirementList
                            .add(shiftTypeSkillRequirement);
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirementId++;
                }

                shiftTypeList.add(shiftTypenew);
                if (shiftTypeMap.containsKey(shiftTypenew.getCode())) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "There are 2 shiftTypes with the same code ("
                                    + shiftTypenew.getCode() + ").");
                }
                shiftTypeMap.put(shiftTypenew.getCode(), shiftTypenew);

                index++;
            }
            nurseRoster.setShiftTypeList(shiftTypeList);
            nurseRoster.setShiftTypeSkillRequirementList(
                    shiftTypeSkillRequirementList);

            int shiftListSize = shiftDateMap.size() * shiftTypeList.size();

            List<Shift> shiftList1 = new ArrayList<>(shiftListSize);
            dateAndShiftTypeToShiftMap = new HashMap<>(shiftListSize);
            dayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftListMap = new HashMap<>(
                    7 * shiftTypeList.size());

            for (ShiftDate shiftDate : newshiftdateList) {
                for (ShiftType shiftType : shiftTypeList) {
                    Shift shift = new Shift();
                    shift.setId(shiftId);
                    shift.setShiftDate(shiftDate);
                    shiftDate.getShiftList().add(shift);
                    ShiftType type = scoreDirector
                            .lookUpWorkingObject(shiftType);
                    shift.setShiftType(type);
                    shift.setIndex(shiftIndex);
                    shift.setRequiredEmployeeSize(0); // Filled in later
                    shiftList1.add(shift);
                    dateAndShiftTypeToShiftMap.put(
                            Pair.of(shiftDate.getDate(), type.getCode()),
                            shift);
                    addShiftToDayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftListMap(shiftDate,
                            type, shift);
                    shiftId++;
                    shiftIndex++;
                    nurseRoster.getShiftList().add(shift);
                    scoreDirector.afterProblemFactAdded(shift);
                }

            }

            List<DayOffRequest> dayOffRequestList;

            List<DayOffDate> dayOffElementList = rosterService.listDayOffDate();

            dayOffRequestList = new ArrayList<>(dayOffElementList.size());
            long id = 0L;
            for (DayOffDate element : dayOffElementList) {
                DayOffRequest dayOffRequest = new DayOffRequest();

                dayOffRequest.setId(id);
                id++;
                int weight = element.getWeight();
                LocalDate shiftDate = element.getDate();

                ShiftDate dateoff = shiftDateMap.get(shiftDate);
                Employee employee = element.getEmployee();
                Employee workingEmployee = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(employee);

                dayOffRequest.setWeight(weight);
                dayOffRequest.setEmployee(workingEmployee);
                dayOffRequest.setShiftDate(dateoff);

                dayOffRequestList.add(dayOffRequest);
                workingEmployee.getDayOffRequestMap().put(dateoff,
                        dayOffRequest);
                nurseRoster.getDayOffRequestList().add(dayOffRequest);

            }

            List<DayOnRequest> dayOnRequestList;

            List<DayOnDate> dayOnElementList1 = rosterService.listDayOnDate();
            long onid = 0L;
            dayOnRequestList = new ArrayList<>(dayOnElementList1.size());
            for (DayOnDate element : dayOnElementList1) {

                DayOnRequest dayOnRequest = new DayOnRequest();

                int weight = element.getWeight();
                LocalDate localshiftDate = element.getDate();

                ShiftDate dateon = shiftDateMap.get(localshiftDate);
                Employee employee = element.getEmployee();
                Employee workingEmployee = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(employee);

                dayOnRequest.setId(onid);
                onid++;
                dayOnRequest.setWeight(weight);
                dayOnRequest.setEmployee(workingEmployee);
                dayOnRequest.setShiftDate(dateon);
                dayOnRequestList.add(dayOnRequest);
                workingEmployee.getDayOnRequestMap().put(dateon, dayOnRequest);
                nurseRoster.getDayOnRequestList().add(dayOnRequest);

            }

            List<ShiftOffRequest> shiftOffRequestList;

            List<ShiftOffDate> shiftOffElementList = (List<ShiftOffDate>) rosterService
                    .listShiftOffDate();
            shiftOffRequestList = new ArrayList<>(shiftOffElementList.size());
            for (ShiftOffDate element : shiftOffElementList) {

                ShiftOffRequest shiftOffRequest = new ShiftOffRequest();

                long ShiftonId = element.getId();
                int weight = element.getWeight();
                Employee employee = element.getEmployee();
                Employee workingEmployee = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(employee);
                LocalDate date1 = element.getDate();

                String shiftcode = element.getShiftType().getCode();
                Shift shift = dateAndShiftTypeToShiftMap
                        .get(Pair.of(date1, shiftcode));

                shiftOffRequest.setId(ShiftonId);
                shiftOffRequest.setEmployee(workingEmployee);
                shiftOffRequest.setShift(shift);
                shiftOffRequest.setWeight(weight);
                shiftOffRequestList.add(shiftOffRequest);
                workingEmployee.getShiftOffRequestMap().put(shift,
                        shiftOffRequest);
                nurseRoster.setShiftOffRequestList(shiftOffRequestList);

            }

            List<ShiftOnRequest> shiftOnRequestList;

            List<ShiftOnDate> shiftOnElementList = (List<ShiftOnDate>) rosterService
                    .listShiftOnDate();
            shiftOnRequestList = new ArrayList<>(shiftOnElementList.size());
            for (ShiftOnDate element : shiftOnElementList) {

                ShiftOnRequest shiftOnRequest = new ShiftOnRequest();

                long ShiftonId = element.getId();
                int weight = element.getWeight();
                Employee employee = element.getEmployee();
                Employee workingEmployee = scoreDirector
                        .lookUpWorkingObject(employee);
                LocalDate date1 = element.getDate();
                String shiftcode = element.getShiftType().getCode();
                Shift shift = dateAndShiftTypeToShiftMap
                        .get(Pair.of(date1, shiftcode));

                shiftOnRequest.setId(ShiftonId);
                shiftOnRequest.setEmployee(workingEmployee);
                shiftOnRequest.setShift(shift);
                shiftOnRequest.setWeight(weight);
                shiftOnRequestList.add(shiftOnRequest);
                workingEmployee.getShiftOnRequestMap().put(shift,
                        shiftOnRequest);
                nurseRoster.setShiftOnRequestList(shiftOnRequestList);

            }

            List<CoverRequirements> coverRequirementElementList1 = (List<CoverRequirements>) rosterService
                    .listCoverRequirements();
            for (CoverRequirements element : coverRequirementElementList1) {
                String type = element.getShiftType().getCode();
                ShiftType shiftTypen = shiftTypeMap.get(type);
                DayOfWeek day = element.getDayOfWeek();
                int req = element.getRequiredEmployeesize();
                Pair<DayOfWeek, ShiftType> key = Pair.of(day, shiftTypen);

                List<Shift> shiftList = dayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftListMap
                        .get(key);

                for (Shift shift : shiftList) {
                    shift.setRequiredEmployeeSize(
                            shift.getRequiredEmployeeSize() + req);

                }
            }
            List<ShiftAssignment> shiftAssignmentList = new ArrayList<>(
                    shiftList1.size());
            long shiftAssignmentId = nurseRoster.getShiftAssignmentList()
                    .get(nurseRoster.getShiftAssignmentList().size() - 1)
                    .getId() + 1L;
            for (Shift shift : shiftList1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < shift.getRequiredEmployeeSize(); i++) {
                    ShiftAssignment newShiftAssignment = new ShiftAssignment();
                    newShiftAssignment.setId(shiftAssignmentId);
                    shiftAssignmentId++;
                    newShiftAssignment.setShift(shift);
                    newShiftAssignment.setIndexInShift(i);
                    shiftAssignmentList.add(newShiftAssignment);
                    nurseRoster.getShiftAssignmentList()
                            .add(newShiftAssignment);
                    scoreDirector.afterEntityAdded(newShiftAssignment);

                }

            }

            // This should move the planning window

            nurseRosterParametrization
                    .setFirstShiftDate(newshiftdateList.get(0));
            nurseRosterParametrization.setLastShiftDate(
                    newshiftdateList.get(newshiftdateList.size() - 1));
            nurseRosterParametrization
                    .setPlanningWindowStart(newshiftdateList.get(0));
            nurseRoster
                    .setNurseRosterParametrization(nurseRosterParametrization);
            scoreDirector
                    .afterProblemPropertyChanged(nurseRosterParametrization);
        //  scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();

        }, true);
    }



    private void addShiftToDayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftListMap(ShiftDate shiftDate, ShiftType shiftType, Shift shift) {
        Pair<DayOfWeek, ShiftType> key = Pair.of(shiftDate.getDayOfWeek(), shiftType);
        List<Shift> dayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftList = dayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftListMap.computeIfAbsent(key,
                k -> new ArrayList<>((shiftDateMap.size() + 6) / 7));
        dayOfWeekAndShiftTypeToShiftList.add(shift);
    }
```

Below is a small debug extract with Full Assert showing no errors

```
step (122), time spent (102920), score (0hard/1342soft), new best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/884), picked move (2019-07-20/E {Reece Bamford} <-> 2019-07-20/D {David Hemmings }).
17:53:37.746 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (123), time spent (103652), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/874), picked move ([[2019-07-23/D, 2019-07-24/E, 2019-07-25/E] {? -> Alana Gill}, [2019-07-23/E, 2019-07-24/E, 2019-07-25/E, 2019-07-26/E, 2019-07-27/D, 2019-07-28/E] {? -> David Hemmings }]).
17:53:38.513 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (124), time spent (104419), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/887), picked move ([[2019-07-15/N] {? -> Sophie Dreves}, [2019-07-15/N] {? -> Reece Bamford}]).
17:53:39.337 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (125), time spent (105243), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/925), picked move (2019-07-22/E {Anthony Phan} <-> 2019-07-22/D {Michael C}).
17:53:40.121 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (126), time spent (106027), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/943), picked move (2019-07-15/L {David Hemmings  -> Clayton Fletcher}).
17:53:40.972 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (127), time spent (106878), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/932), picked move (2019-07-22/E {Sophie Dreves} <-> 2019-07-22/L {Karen Ahrens}).
17:53:41.815 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (128), time spent (107721), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/932), picked move ([[2019-07-21/E, 2019-07-22/E, 2019-07-23/D, 2019-07-24/L, 2019-07-25/D, 2019-07-26/E] {? -> Michael C}, [2019-07-21/D, 2019-07-22/E, 2019-07-23/E, 2019-07-24/L, 2019-07-25/L, 2019-07-26/N] {? -> Karen Ahrens}]).
17:53:42.635 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (129), time spent (108541), score (0hard/1342soft),     best score (0hard/1342soft), accepted/selected move count (800/950), picked move ([[2019-07-19/D, 2019-07-20/E, 2019-07-21/L] {? -> Gemma Nevin}, [2019-07-19/D, 2019-07-20/L] {? -> David Hemmings }]).
17:53:43.481 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (130), time spent (109387), score (0hard/1343soft), new best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/950), picked move ([[2019-07-15/D, 2019-07-16/E, 2019-07-17/E, 2019-07-18/E, 2019-07-19/E] {? -> David Hemmings }, [2019-07-16/N] {? -> Isabella}, [2019-07-19/D, 2019-07-20/L] {? -> Isabella}]).
17:53:44.290 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (131), time spent (110196), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/944), picked move (2019-07-28/E {David Hemmings } <-> 2019-07-28/L {Anthony Phan}).
17:53:45.053 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (132), time spent (110959), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/919), picked move ([[2019-07-15/L, 2019-07-16/L, 2019-07-17/N] {? -> Lisa Coull}, [2019-07-15/L, 2019-07-16/L, 2019-07-17/N] {? -> Clayton Fletcher}]).
17:53:45.857 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (133), time spent (111763), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/936), picked move (2019-07-19/N {Anthony Phan} <-> 2019-07-19/N {Sophie Dreves}).
17:53:46.638 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (134), time spent (112544), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/952), picked move (2019-07-23/E {David Hemmings } <-> 2019-07-23/D {Alana Gill}).
17:53:47.437 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (135), time spent (113343), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/926), picked move ([[2019-07-15/N] {? -> Sophie Dreves}, [2019-07-15/N] {? -> Reece Bamford}]).
17:53:48.253 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (136), time spent (114159), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/963), picked move ([[2019-07-27/E, 2019-07-28/E] {? -> Isabella}, [2019-07-27/N, 2019-07-28/N] {? -> Sophie Dreves}]).
17:53:49.035 [l-3-thread-2] DEBUG     LS step (137), time spent (114941), score (0hard/1343soft),     best score (0hard/1343soft), accepted/selected move count (800/964), picked move (2019-07-17/N {Lisa Coull} <-> 2019-07-17/N {Clayton Fletcher}).
```

Comment: And turning on FULL_ASSERT nor FAST_ASSERT throws no exceptions?

Comment: Correct no errors are shown. Dates in debug for the advance are correct all looks good. Just in this case get to 18 Shift for 11 employees and 10 for the other

Comment: It gets close eg 18 for some 17, 19, 20 for the others and maybe a 12 for the Parttime employee etc but never 18 for the 11 full time and 10 for the parttime. First run before advance is good. All 11 get 9 shifts and the parttime 5 (perfect)

Comment: My project can located here for anyone who can help. https://github.com/rod182211/NiksRoster